# an exercise in Galois theory about polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

find a field $F$ and different polynomials $f(X),g(X)\in F[X]$ that for every $\alpha \in F$ we have $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$.

prove that it is impossible if $F$ is infinite.

i think this example works:
$F=Z_2 , f(X)=0 , g(X)=x^2-x $

am i true?

how i can prove it when $F$ is infinite?

thanks

Comment: You're correct about $x^2 - x$ in $\mathbf{Z}_2$. Do you know the theorem that a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots? What polynomial could that be applied to here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your example is right and, in general, in $\mathbb{F}_p$, $f(X)=0$ and $g(X)=X^p-X$ are an example of this sort.

If $F$ is infinite, let $d=\max\{\deg f, \deg g\}$ and pick $a_1,\ldots, a_{d+1}\in F$ all distinct (you can, because $F$ is infinite). Then $f(X)-g(X)=p(X)$ is a polynomial with $\deg p\leq d$ and $p(a_i)=0$ for every $a_i$, because you have that $f(a)=g(a)$ for every $a\in F$. But a polynomial, with coefficients in a field, of degree $d$ vanishing for $d+1$ values in such field has to be zero.
Then $f\equiv g$.